# Which software to use to solve $1000.00116=\frac{1000}{\left(1+x\right)^{16}}+\frac{1-\left(1+x\right)^{-16}}{x}$?

Tags: math-software

I have the following equation that I need to solve:

$$1000.00116=\frac{1000}{\left(1+x\right)^{16}}+\frac{1-\left(1+x\right)^{-16}}{x}$$

However, software I use is refusing to do it. Which software/web is capable of solving it? Or could you please show me the answer?

Thanks

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000.00116%3D%5Cfrac%7B1000%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2Bx%5Cright%29%5E%7B16%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Cleft%281%2Bx%5Cright%29%5E%7B-16%7D%7D%7Bx%7D) is a _pretty neat_ resource.

Comment: @AndrewChin thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a finance problem. Consider

$$y=\frac{1000}{\left(1+x\right)^{16}}+\frac{1-\left(1+x\right)^{-16}}{x}$$ and expand as a series around $x=0$ to get

$$y=1016-16136 x+136816 x^2-819876 x^3+3891504 x^4-15558264 x^5+54434544
   x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Using series reversion
$$x=t+\frac{17102 t^2}{2017}+\frac{756491143 t^3}{8136578}+\frac{9312920857507
   t^4}{8205738913}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1016-y}{16136}$

Working with whole numbers and the value of $y$, this gives $$t=\frac{399971}{403400000}$$ for which the truncated inverse series gives
$$x=\frac{217284880812466746896433664885508741308467}{217300772456778118887476800000000
   000000000000}\approx 0.000999926868$$ while the exact solution should be            $0.000999926882$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
1000.00116-\frac{1-(x+1)^{16}}{x}-\frac{1000}{(x+1)^{16}}\approx 16.0012+16120 x-135440 x^2+O\left(x^3\right)
$$

solving for $x$ we have

$$
x = \cases{
-0.000984485\\
0.120004
}
$$

The first value gives an error of $0.000783992$. Now we can proceed using an iterative procedure like Newton-Raphson to approximate arbitrarily those values.